# Calling a task via celery beat which is inside a folder throws Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I have the following celery beat schedule

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'task-number-one': {
    'task': 'frontend.tasks2.tasks.test_task', #this doesn't work throws following error
    'schedule': 1.0
  },
}
```

and the following error comes when I start celery beat and worker

> [2018-08-20 19:26:31,606: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'frontend.tasks2.tasks.test_task'.
>   The message has been ignored and discarded.
>
> Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
>   Or maybe you're using relative imports?

**I have the following project structure**

```
frontend
|-tasks2
|   |-tasks.py
|     |-test_task()
|-tasks.py
    |-test_task()
```

But if I change the beat schedule to following it starts working, both `test_task()` functions are same.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'frontend.tasks.test_task', # this does work properly
        'schedule': 1.0
     },
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Have you included an `__init__.py` file in your `frontend` directory?

Comment: yeah i tried that as well. but not working